# Расставить знаки препинания

Tags: пунктуация

Выделения запятыми слова *"может"* мне понятно (оно может быть вводным, а может и нет), но, когда добавляется частица *"даже"*, я теряюсь, так как интонационно не выделяется. Как расставить знаки препинания здесь: *"Скажу громко может даже кто-нибудь услышит"*. С пояснениями, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Усилительные частицы при вводных словах не отделяются от них запятой: "***Уж вероятно***, это так, поскольку нет никаких противопоказаний".  (http://www.ngebooks.com/book_27869_chapter_32_x_x_x.html)

У Вас как раз такой случай. **Даже** - усилительная частица при вводном слове **может**. Поэтому запятая после **может** не нужна.

Ещё интересная информация, касающаяся Вашего примера:

Вводные слова и сочетания слов, стоящие на границе однородных членов или частей сложного предложения и относящиеся к следующему за ними слову или предложению, не отделяются от него запятой (вторая запятая опускается с целью указания на отнесенность вводного слова к последующей части предложения): Лось шел скачками в сторону озер, должно быть спешил на водопой (Пауст.); Послышался резкий стук, должно быть сорвалась ставня (Ч.)   ***ПАС Лопатина***

Поэтому не нужна запятая и после частицы даже:"Скажу громко, может даже кто-нибудь услышит".